# Wrong frame values during animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, frame, uicontainerview

I want to make an animation like iOS home screen folder. I have a Container View in a Main View Controller and in the Container View I switch between two View Controllers with an animation.
Here is the code of Main View Controller Class:

```
class MainContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    let duration = 1.0
    var presenting = true
    var originFrame = CGRect.zero
    var indexPathSelectedCell: IndexPath?

    var dismissCompletion: (()->())?


    func cycle(fromViewController: UIViewController, toViewController: UIViewController) {

        let folderViewC = (presenting ? fromViewController : toViewController) as! ViewController
        let projectViewC = (presenting ? toViewController : fromViewController) as! ProjectViewController

        let cellView = (presenting ? (folderViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: folderViewC.folderCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!.first!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell).folderView : projectViewC.containerView)!
        let cellSnapshot = cellView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)!
        let cellFrame = containerView.convert(cellView.frame, from: cellView.superview)
        cellSnapshot.frame = cellFrame
        cellView.isHidden = true

        toViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.frame
        toViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        toViewController.view.alpha = 0


        presenting ? (projectViewC.containerView.isHidden = true) : ((folderViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: self.indexPathSelectedCell!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell).folderView.isHidden = true)

        fromViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(toViewController)
        self.containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
        self.containerView.addSubview(cellSnapshot)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {


            toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0

            let finalFrame = self.presenting ? projectViewC.containerView.frame : self.containerView.convert((folderViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: self.indexPathSelectedCell!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell).folderView.frame, from: (folderViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: self.indexPathSelectedCell!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell).folderView.superview)

            cellSnapshot.frame = finalFrame
        }) { (_) in

            if !self.presenting {
                self.dismissCompletion?()
            }

            self.presenting ? (projectViewC.containerView.isHidden = false) : ((folderViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: self.indexPathSelectedCell!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell).folderView.isHidden = false)

            cellSnapshot.removeFromSuperview()
            fromViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
            fromViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
            toViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: nil)

        }

    }

}
```

All the code works correctly except `let finalFrame = self.presenting ? projectViewC.containerView.frame : self.containerView.convert((folderViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: self.indexPathSelectedCell!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell).folderView.frame, from: (folderViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: self.indexPathSelectedCell!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell).folderView.superview)` that set `finalFrame` to a wrong value:

- when it is presenting the Snapshot goes in the middle of the screen
- when it is dismissing the Snapshot goes near his right position.

The `let finalFrame = self.presenting ? projectViewC.containerView.frame : self.containerView.convert((folderViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: self.indexPathSelectedCell!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell).folderView.frame, from: (folderViewC.folderCollectionView.cellForItem(at: self.indexPathSelectedCell!) as! FolderCollectionViewCell).folderView.superview)` line works in this way:

- check if it is presenting
- if it is presenting set the constant to the *frame* value of the final *folder* view
- if it is dismissing convert the *frame* value of the folderView of the selected Collection View Cell from  the superview of this folderView

Here is the whole project: https://github.com/ale00/OnteamAnon

Comment: Sorry if I've made some mistakes with the language, I'm italian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using auto layout for the size of your containerView in projectViewController, you need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on `self.containerView` after this part of your code:

> ```
> self.addChildViewController(toViewController)
> self.containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
> self.containerView.addSubview(cellSnapshot)
> ```

So it becomes:

```
self.addChildViewController(toViewController)
self.containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
self.containerView.addSubview(cellSnapshot)
self.containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now! I thought this was the problem but then I didn't test it...